How to increase Font size or scale the font in existing pdf pages using PDFBOX or ITEXT?
I want to make large font of existing PDF.
18pt Bold Font
24pt Bold Font
Apply for all the text in all pages of pdf. The text in entire pages will increase from current size to 18pt or 24pt more.
That definitely increase the number of pages. So that we should handle automatically.
below image you can see that the right side content stream is increased size after enlarge text using "InDesign". Same thing I want to achieve programatically. The increased font can read easily by visually weak persons.
Any suggestion and code snippets helpful to me.


You don't only want to increase font sizes. Increasing font sizes will not definitely increase the number of pages as you say but simply have part of the text off-page (and invisible) or letters overlapping each other. What you want is actually re-flowing the text with a larger font, probably re-layout'ing all contents. This in general is highly non-trivial.

Basically there should never be a need to resize all contents as hinted to a larger size. PDF is accepted as second best format for accessibility as it works well for the partially sighted or blind. Thus has inherent features that avoid the need to enlarge text. Let's consider why with your minimal examples. I have emulated your offered extracts. Although they are out of context (so placement may be slightly off) that does not affect considerations in programming the maths.

There are many simple ways to "Upscale" fonts. by far the simplest is add /UserUnit 2 to double all contents so that 12 points wide becomes 2x12 points wide. Very easy to do 3 0 obj<</UserUnit  2/Contents 4 0 R
As a side note, both your examples are in effect one single printers unit wide, which can be considered a default of 1/72" but that can be changed. One has been upscaled 12 X 12 Y and the other upscaled 29.48 X 29.48 Y
Instantly everything is twice as big. the same 1 point and 29.48 point high fonts are untouched but now twice as big on the screen.

But note the page size has quadrupled to 2 x A4 wide and 2 X A4 high this is necessary to contain all the contents in the same independent page, since PDF page contents cannot flow between pages.
Now we arrive at why there is no need to double the page contents, is because we can do that easier by use Zoom 200% in the already produced page and see contents as 4 times bigger or clearer, without upsetting or upscaling page size or content.

You implied it should be possible to take the 12 point high line to 24 and the maths is identical we double the width of everything by change for example the 1 point font definition to 2 points e.g. /T1_1 1 Tf to /T1_1 2 Tf also easy but damaging to all the offsetting. Now you would need to move every single character to a new location, and it's worse when lines are in proximity as they overlap when upscaled.

